# Getting empty entry in a drop-down list in PHP

Tags: php

I want to display two colors in a drop-down list.
For some products it will be single color only.
When i want to display a single color, it is giving an empty entry in the drop-down list.

```
<tr>
    <td style="color:#e74c3c">Color:</td>
    <td>
        <select>
            <option><?php echo $obj->color; ?></option>
            <option><?php echo $obj->color_2; ?></option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have two columns in the database, *color* and *color-2*.

Comment: Put colors in array. and run a foreach loop. It will help you in future.

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr>
<td style="color:#e74c3c">Color:</td>
<td>
<select>
    <?php echo $obj->color != null: "<option>$obj->color</option>" : "" ?>
    <?php echo $obj->color_2 != null: "<option>$obj->color_2</option>" : "" ?>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a condition for the second color if it exists, if not the option will not be viewed in the first place:

```
    <tr>
    <td style="color:#e74c3c">Color:</td>
    <td>
    <select><option><?php  echo $obj->color; ?></option>
    <?php if(isset($obj->color_2) && !empty($obj->color_2)) { ?>
   <option><?php  echo $obj->color_2; ?></option> <?php } ?>
    </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
```